# Bootstrap 'nav tabs' works incompletely in jsp

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'am using Bootstrap in jsp file, and using tag `nav nav-tabs`, here is my code in `.jsp` file:

before `</head>`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>content sales</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
```

and before `</body>`

```
<!-- boostrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
<script>
    $('#myTab a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show')
    })
</script>
```

I add this script code because i try solution from [Bootstrap nav tabs/pills works only at first interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808123/bootstrap-nav-tabs-pills-works-only-at-first-interaction), but it doesn't work.

and here is my body content:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">All content</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="#unbought" data-toggle="tab">Unbought content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- all content -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <table class="table">
                something in table using jsp
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- unbought-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="unbought">
            <table class="table">
                something in table using jsp            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the problem is when i access this jsp file in chrome(version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)), the first time i click `All content`, `Unbought content`,it works fine, but when i try to click again, i can not switch from `All content` to `Unbought content` or from `Unbought content` to `All content`.

Can anybody help?

---

I tried put all the content into a html file, the result is same with jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

I change a link source of Bootstrap and it works fine. So i think the problem maybe is the source of Bootstrap have not been included correctly.